# Yarn parsing job logs stored in hdfs

Tags: json, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Is there any parser, which I can use to parse the json present in yarn job logs(jhist files) which gets stored in hdfs to extract information from it.

Answer (score 2):

The second line in the .jhist file is the avro schema for the other jsons in the file. Meaning that you can create avro data out of the jhist file.
For this you could use [avro-tools-1.7.7.jar](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/gettingstartedjava.html)

```
# schema is the second line
sed -n '2p;3q' file.jhist > schema.avsc

# removing the first two lines
sed '1,2d' file.jhist > pfile.jhist

# finally converting to avro data
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar fromjson pfile.jhist --schema-file schema.avsc > file.avro
```

You've got an avro data, which you can for example import to a Hive table, and make queries on it.

Comment: Can this be used to parse avro binary files as well? I tried parsing .jhist file which is in avro binary format and while trying to convert, it throws error when ever it encounters some binary characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Rumen](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/tools/rumen/package-summary.html), a parsing tool from the apache ecosystem
or When you visit the web UI, go to job history and look for the job for which you want to read .jhist file. Hit the Counters link at the left,now you will be able see an API which gives you all the parameters and the value like CPU time in milliseconds etc. which will read from a .jhist file itself.

Comment: Thanks, man! It was really helpful for me.