# Converting .jhist files to JSON format

Tags: json, macos, type-conversion

How can I convert .jhist files to json format in OSX?

I wonder if there are validated software packages or commands for doing so?

About [.jhist files](https://www.altiscale.com/hadoop-blog/top-10-hadoop-yarn-part-1/): Another important log for MapReduce jobs is the job history file (.jhist). These files contain a wealth of performance data on the execution of Mappers and Reducers, including HDFS statistics, data volume processed, memory allocated etc. We configure our History Server to write the jhist files to HDFS periodically using the mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir parameter in yarn-site.xml

Comment: I can't even google the file format specs for jhsit. Nothing on wiki. If you want an answer you should provide more info.

Comment: I updated the question!

Comment: You haven't provided specification (schema). If it's XML type of document then use XML to JSON convert. Please provide specification of jhist file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in the full log history you could [parse as an avro file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091983/3616914). If you are interested in one big json file with aggregated counters, you could check out [Rumen](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/tools/rumen/package-summary.html), a parsing tool from the apache ecosystem.

An example run of Rumen:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-rumen-2.5.0-cdh5.2.6.jar \
    org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder \
    file:///tmp/job-trace.json \
    file:///tmp/job-topology.json \
    file:///sample-job-histories/job_201211091010_0001_1352484738664_word+count
```

and you get the aggregated counters in job-trace.json, and the topology in job-topology.json